# outlook "To Do" items into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

First off, I'm new to VBA, with about 20 hours of training.

I'm trying to export items from Outlook 2010 to Excel 2010.  I want to grab all the unfinished "To Do" items from Outlook and throw them into Excel with one item per row, and columns for item parameters (like Subject, Due Date, attachments, etc.).

Here's the first pass that actually does what I explained, and imports only tasks (tasks are a subset of all to do items, from what I understand) and their Subject/Due Date:

```
Function GetOutlookApp() As Object

On Error Resume Next
  Set GetOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub getOlTasks()

Dim olApp As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim olnameSpace As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
Dim taskFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim tasks As Object ' Outlook.Items
Dim tsk As Object

Set olApp = GetOutlookApp
Set olnameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set taskFolder = olnameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(13)  'olFolderTasks is folder# 13, apparently
Set tasks = taskFolder.Items

  For x = 1 To tasks.Count

    Set tsk = tasks.Item(x)
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False
      Selection.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop

'Fill in Data
    If Not tsk.Complete Then
      ActiveCell.Value = tsk.Subject
      Selection.Offset(0, 1).Activate
      ActiveCell.Value = tsk.DueDate
      Selection.Offset(1, -1).Activate
    End If

  Next x

End Sub
```

I tried to do this with only "tasks" items, everything was going smoothly until I realized that tasks can't have attachments.  When I have an email w/attachment that I turn into a task, I lose the attachment.  Apparently what I need to do is import all "To Do items", rather than just tasks.

So My questions are:

1) What folder number is olFolderToDo?  I have seen people run code like:

```
Set taskFolder = olnameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks) 'rather than GetDefaultFolder(13)
```

which would lead me to believe I should be able to just use olFolderToDo, but when I try to use the *name* of the folder in my first example rather than the *number*, I get an invalid argument runtime error.  If anyone knows why, I'd be interested to know.

2) How would I go about importing an attachment from an email to a specific cell in excel?

Comment: I don't think there's a "built-in" folder for "ToDo", so it doesn't have an enumeration like 'olFolderTasks'.  If you want to get a user-created folder then you should be able to use something like: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

Comment: Ah OK, thank you.  I will do some more research on this is post what I find out.  My first question would be, how do I sync all of my "todo items" from wherever they are to one folder that I can use as you mention?

Comment: Ok, so you are correct, there is no "ToDo" folder like I was hoping.  Perhaps there is a flag on every item that I flag in OutLook (how apt) as a ToDo item.  It seems I'll have to go through my inbox, filter out the messages without a flag, then extract.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [OlDefaultFolders Enumeration (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861868%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
Name         Value  Description

olFolderToDo  28    The To Do folder.
```